# Релизный ключ Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Как получить релизный ключ для приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. [Get an Android certificate and the Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key)

> 1. Retrieve information about your application's certificate.
> 2. Register a project in the Google Developers Console and add the Maps API as a service for the project.
> 3. Request one or more keys.
> 4. Add your key to your application and begin development.

Вам понадобится получить информацию о сертификате с помощью `keytool`, добавить проект в Developers Console, добавить сервис Maps API, запросить ключ, добавить ключ в приложение.

Более подробная информация со всеми деталями по ссылке выше.

Comment: Ранее получил debug ключ для отладки, с помощью keytool получил новый SHA1.
теперь в гугл-консоли перезаписать старый ключ используя новый SHA1?

Comment: @Александр Там же описано и как получать релизный.